# Last Loop Iterations doesn't rename the Target Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

There's this loop that I'm running to extract distinct `Job Name`, place it in a new table with `Job Name` as its name. Almost all iterations of the loop works, except for roughly **last two iterations** (Containing both `WEB` and `EDV` keywords), which works as they fetch the table values, but **doesn't rename the worksheet**.

Here's the VBA Code that I'm running:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Create_New_Sheets()

    Dim xRCount As Long
    Dim xSht As Worksheet
    Dim xNSht As Worksheet
    Dim I As Long
    Dim xTRrow As Integer
    Dim xCol As New Collection
    Dim xSUpdate As Boolean
    Set xSht = ActiveSheet
    On Error Resume Next

    Dim strSearch As String
    Dim aCell As Range

    strSearch = "Job Title"

    Set aCell = xSht.Rows(1).Find(What:=strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    xRCount = xSht.Cells(xSht.Rows.Count, aCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
    xTRrow = xSht.Range("Table1[#Headers]").Cells(1).Row
    For I = 2 To xRCount
        Call xCol.Add(xSht.Cells(I, aCell.Column).Text, xSht.Cells(I, aCell.Column).Text)
    Next
    xSUpdate = Application.ScreenUpdating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For I = 1 To xCol.Count
        Call xSht.Range("Table1[#Headers]").AutoFilter(aCell.Column, CStr(xCol.Item(I))) 'filter tool
        Set xNSht = Nothing
        Set xNSht = Worksheets(CStr(xCol.Item(I)))
        If xNSht Is Nothing Then
            Set xNSht = Worksheets.Add(, Sheets(Sheets.Count)) 'add new worksheet
            xNSht.Name = CStr(xCol.Item(I)) 'name new worksheet
        Else
            xNSht.Move , Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        End If
        xSht.Range("A" & xTRrow & ":A" & xRCount).EntireRow.Copy xNSht.Range("A1") 'get filtered copy
        'xNSht.RowHeight = 409
        'xNSht.ColumnWidth = 255
        'xNSht.Rows.AutoFit
        xNSht.Columns.AutoFit
        Call xNSht.Range("Table1[#Headers]").AutoFilter(aCell.Column, CStr(xCol.Item(I))) 'filter tool
        Cells.Find(What:=strSearch, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
            :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
            False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        If ActiveCell.Value Like "WEB*" And ActiveCell.Value Like "*EDV*" Then
            Debug.Print "TRUE"
            ActiveSheet.Name = ActiveCell.Value 'It also doesn't rename the Worksheet
        Else
            Debug.Print "FALSE"
        End If
    Next
    xSht.Activate
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
    Application.ScreenUpdating = xSUpdate

End Sub
```

Upon watching related variables, the values **does change accordingly**, but the `xNSht.Name` doesn't change according to `CStr(xCol.Item(I))` when the `Job Title` has both `WEB` and `EDV` on it.

Also, take note that I've commented `xNSht.RowHeight = 409` and `xNSht.ColumnWidth = 255` as they throw a **Compile Error** *(which is another question for another time)*; and I've also tried to put a **redundant rename if-statement**, but it also doesn't rename the worksheet.

Comment: Get rid of On Error Resume next until and unless you know how to handle and trap errors. currently, that's swallowing any runtime errors which would let us know more info about what's going wrong here. report back with the error details :)

Comment: And what's the cell value which doesn't rename a sheet? there are a few restrictions on sheet names it seems likely you're running afoul of one or more of those.  32 characters, some special characters aren't allowed, must be unique within the workbook.

Comment: @DavidZemens same without On Error Resume Next
also, `WEB_WW_EDV_***_*_*_***_********`  mostly like that

Comment: that seems impossible. :) inconsistencies can't exist, when one appears to exist, check the premises. what's the cell value when Debug.Print "True"?

Comment: There's also a problem on that: it also doesn't rename the worksheet name, which it should rename.

Comment: one thing at a time broseph.

Comment: there's several statements in this code that would cause possible runtime errors. `Set xNSht=...` will error if that name doesn't exist, which is why you test for Nothing on the next line, but without error handling the code won't get that far.  can we back up a step -- which specific line are you concerned about right now? let's step through this Ok?

Comment: `xNSht.Name = CStr(xCol.Item(I)) 'name new worksheet`
basically, this step. `CStr(xCol.Item(I)) contains a value, but it doesn't rename the worksheet

Comment: That line is never going to be hit, from what I can tell. The only way that statement executes is if the preceding `If xNSht Is Nothing` = True. But for that to be Tru, the preceding `Set xNSht = ...` would raise an Index Out of Range error.

Comment: I already got it. I forgot to view the character length (the latter exceeded by 1, so it wasn't accepted as character name). With that, I want to have the whole name if it's on or under 31 characters. If not, it'll be trimmed to 28 characters with a "..." in the end. Thanks for the help